# separate a column into two columns (sql)

Tags: php, sql

I have column with the following information:

```
Author  varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci
```

the programmer who designed the website before me used this column to store two things! 
first, the name of the author in English, then his/her name in Arabic ! 
so, all the data in that column have the same structure :`تووياما أيما (Tooyama Ema)`
between the parenthesis is the name in English. outside the parentheses the name in Arabic. 
Is there any way to take the English name and put it in a new column. plus remove the parenthesis? I can use both PHP and SQL, so please can you give me a solution with those two languages?
I want the result to look like this :

> Author : `تووياما أيما`
>   Author in English : `Tooyama Ema`

I am talking about many rows with the same structure. and I want to change the structure in the database.

Comment: Sounds easy enough. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I did not try anything. I have no idea on how to seperate it. The column `Author` have 20000 rows. I want to do all this automatically with no mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend an db-driven solution, should take less time coding and running than using PHP.

Not sure on the table name, but here is the meat of what you need, change to your liking:

(assuming rough table definition of)

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  Author varchar(255),
  primary key (id)
)
```

An alter table for the new columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN `arabic_name` varchar(255) AFTER `Author`;
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN `english_name` varchar(255) AFTER `arabic_name`;
```

A simple update statement to migrate the data (not the prettiest, but works just fine):

```
 UPDATE Test
 SET
 arabic_name = SUBSTR(TRIM(Author), 1, LOCATE(' ', TRIM(Author)) - 1),
 english_name = SUBSTR(TRIM(Author), LOCATE('(', TRIM(Author)) + 1, LOCATE(')', TRIM(Author)) -  LOCATE('(', TRIM(Author)) - 1);
```

Comment: This is much more sensible.  No need to make a one-off application to do this.

Comment: I agree. This is way better than the other answer. =) +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "تووياما أيما (Tooyama Ema)";
preg_match("/(.+) \((.+)\)/", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: but that is for only one row I want to do it in all the rows. and I want to change the structure in the SQL. not in the PHP.

Comment: @shnisaka: You will need to select all of the records, do the processing, and then update. I suggest you use prepared statements in conjunction with transactions. See the [PDO manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for more details.